# Could not deduce template arguments (for a simple class function)

Tags: c++, lambda, functional-programming, variadic-templates

Suppose we have the following class function:

```
struct Entity {}

template <typename Component, typename... Components>
void each(std::function<void(Entity&, Component&, Components&...)> fn) {}
```

Calling it like below produces the "could not deduce template argument for..." error:

```
.each<int>([](Entity& e, int& i) {}
```

However, this works as expected:

```
std::function<void(Entity&, int&)> x = [](Entity& e, int& i) {}

.each<int>(x);
```

Straight forward, what's going on here and how to solve this?

Comment: Why not just `template<class Fn> void each(Fn&& fn)`? Lambda is not `std::function` (but can be converted into one).

Comment: Because `.each` forwards the `std::function` to another function and wrong template params can be difficult and messy to deal with on the error log.

Comment: You can't deduce template parameters for `std::function` from something that is not `std::function`. You need one level of indirection.

Comment: So there's no way to achieve this other than your first comment?

Comment: I guess, no. First take `Fn&& fn`, then convert it into `std::function` and call your `each`.

Comment: How is this conversion done? One can input anything for `fn`: an simple integer, an object, a function pointer and so on. This is why I implicitly used `std::function` instead.

Comment: Do you have access to C++17?

Comment: Yes... abcdefgh

Comment: How about this https://godbolt.org/z/BwTa-z ?